# How should I structure these before_actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently, my ApplicationController looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  include CurrentUser

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authorize
  before_action :get_current_user

  protected
    def authorize
      unless User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
        redirect_to login_url, notice: "Please log in"
      end
    end
end
```

As you can see, `authorize` checks to make sure a user is login, and if not - redirects them to the login page. This works perfectly.

On the "front facing" pages, where users don't have to be logged in, I do this:

```
skip_before_action :authorize, only: [:names, :of, :ok, :pages]
```

Now, I have added some pages where elevated privileges are required, so that method would (I think) look something like this:

```
def check_for_elevated_role
    u = User.find(id: session[:user_id])
    unless u.role >= 10
        redirect_to some_url, notice: "Insufficient Role"
    end
end
```

My question is, what is the *best* way to implement this? Should I simply add this as a before action to the pages I want to lock down, or (Like I did with authorize), add this to the `ApplicationController` and skip this on pages where users don't need privileges (that's the safe way, right?). Whatever the case, **can you show me what the before_actions should look like?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer as it's a little long as a comment.

You most probably want to create a different controller with that `before_action` and inherit from that controller

```
class AuthorizeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_admin

  protected

  def authorize_admin
    # your logic here
  end
end

class ControllerThatNeedsAuthorizationController < AuthorizeController
  skip_before_action :action_that_doesnt_need_authorization
end
```

Comment: I like this. Much more practical than stacking the before actions. Thanks!